# Split option groups in a dropdown based on the property of a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I am trying to split my option groups in a dropdown into two categories, unassigned and assigned.

For example, if this is my data (unassigned=false):

```
Bob, true
Steven, false
Mary, false
John, true
```

I would want it to output this:

```
<select name="city[country_id]">
  <optgroup label="Unassigned">
    <option value="2">Steven</option>
    <option value="3">Mary</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Assigned">
    <option value="1">Bob</option>
    <option value="4">John</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have been trying to use the collection_select helper from rails as well as the group helpers, but have been unsuccessful.  Is there any rails helper way to do this?  If not, how could I produce this result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for this purpose. It will group the elements in a Hash based on values resulting from the Block. I do not know what data structure you use to store your data, I am assuming a Hash for my answer.

```
data = {
  Bob: true,
  Steven: false,
  Mary: false,
  John: true
}

Hash[data.group_by { |_,v| v ? 'Assigned' : 'Unassigned' }.map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:first)] }]
# => {"Assigned"=>[:Bob, :John], "Unassigned"=>[:Steven, :Mary]}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition), which partitions the Enumerable into a `true` Array and `false` Array based on the return value of the passed Block:

```
# Partition data based on their 'assigned' value
data.partition { |name, assigned| assigned }.map { |partition| Hash[partition] }
# => [{:Bob=>true, :John=>true}, {:Steven=>false, :Mary=>false}]
```